# PHP can't pass a variable from one file to an include file : Undefined variable

Tags: php, variables, scope, include

Hi I've tried a few solutions I've seen on SO but none seem to resolve my problem.

I have a variable **$C_userUsername** in my login page (**login.php**) that im trying to pass to an include file (**head.php**). The idea is that on successful log in the username will show on the page.

Here are the bits of code.

**login.php:**

```
 if ($valid) {

             global $C_userUsername;

             $T_userUserName = trim($userUsername);

             $C_userUsername = htmlentities($T_userUserName);


             } else {

               echo "<br>Invalid user name or password<br>";
            }
```

**head.php:**

```
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li id='regLi'><a href='registration.php'>Register</a></li>";
echo "<li id='onLi'><a href='login.php'>Login</a></li>";
echo "<li id='userLi'><a href='#'>$C_userUsername  is logged in</a></li>";

echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - No idea where `$valid` and `$userUsername` are defined or how they're included.

Comment: Is it all happening in the sane execution? PHP variables, global or not, are only available on the scope of execution. Storing the value in the session or some king of storage will solve your problem

Comment: Is the second snippet of code, from `head.php`, defined within a function or is it being `include`d from within a function by `login.php`? If so,  that is likely your problem as [PHP variable scope](http://php.net/language.variables.scope) rules state that local variables (any variable initialized within a function) is by default local to that function and does not explicitly export from the global scope. Since the `include` construct inherits the calling scope, then using `include 'head.php'` inside of a function makes `$C_userUsername` a local variable by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save it in a `$_SESSION`. You can check if the `session` is set, ifso echo the sessions value.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username
```

Set this after the login of the user.

```
echo $_SESSION['username']
```

Where you want to display the user his username.

Comment: Genius! That's kind of the point of sessions. Thanks working now.

Comment: @MauriceGreenland great, but it's always nice to figure out the *real* problem and why your code initially failed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thats true. I don't understand why it didnt work. It is my understanding that if you declare a varable as global then you can use it elsewhere (other files).  $valid is just a flag, true when validation is passed. The script in login.php passes validation fine thats why I didn't put all the rest of the script above it.

Comment: @MauriceGreenland Using error reporting would have helped during your development. Keep that in mind for later use ;-) *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to write the code as you want.
First one is as follows:

```
$_SESSION['user_name']=$user_name;
```

For using global variable you have to include that page where you want to access variable.

```
$user_name="user name";
include('file_name.php');
```

In file_name.php file you have to access variable like

```
$user_name=$GLOBALS['user_name'];
```